# the_excerpt function not showing image

Tags: functions, content, excerpt

I am having posts with images.In single post page all
   contents displaying well with image. But in blog page , the content only displaying not an image.

How can i make it to display

For example,
http://www.beezid.com/blog

this blog displaying images with read more link

but not in my case
http://optisolbusiness.com/gonzobidz/blog/

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not set an explicit excerpt for your post in the post editor, WordPress by default calls [`wp_trim_excerpt()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1844) to auto-generate an excerpt. This function throws out all HTML tags to make life simple. [`the_content()` does not do this](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/post-template.php#L219) when it splits your post on a `<!--more-->` tag.

If you don't want this default behavior you can [unhook the `wp_trim_excerpt()` function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L150) and duplicate it with one of your own that does not remove HTML tags. Watch out when you split your text somewhere: call [`force_balance_tags()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/formatting.php#L993) to make sure your excerpt does not end with `Some <strong>great news... [Read more]`, because everything after it will be bold too. You will also have to see how this works with embedded content: if you remove some of the tags for a Flash video you also won't get what you expect.